# c# ado.net cant save long strings to sql database

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I'm trying to get an input as text and save it to SQL table,
the code works fine if the string isn't too long, but when you exceed from about 70 characters the `SaveChanges();` command isn't able to save the data.
SQL data type is set to `nvarchar(max)`. Any idea?

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Model.TBL_USERS USR = new Model.TBL_USERS();
    USR.USR_NAME = txtNAME.Text;
    USR.USR_LAST = txtLAST.Text;
    USR.USR_MOBILE = txtMOBILE.Text;
    USR.USR_TEL1 = txtTEL1.Text ;
    USR.USR_ADDRESS = txtADDRESS.Text;
    USR.USR_COMPANY = txtCOMPANY.Text;
    //USR.USR_COMPANY = "=chrome..69i57.13150j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8";
    DB.TBL_USERS.Add(USR);
    DB.SaveChanges();

    dataGridView1.DataSource = "";
    dataGridView1.DataSource = DB.TBL_USERS.ToList();
}
```

this is the whole code in the solution :

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    Model.SAMA_User_CRM_V1 DB = new Model.SAMA_User_CRM_V1();
    int IDGRID;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = DB.TBL_USERS.ToList();

    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Model.TBL_USERS USR = new Model.TBL_USERS();
        USR.USR_NAME = txtNAME.Text;
        USR.USR_LAST = txtLAST.Text;
        USR.USR_MOBILE = txtMOBILE.Text;
        USR.USR_TEL1 = txtTEL1.Text ;
        USR.USR_ADDRESS = txtADDRESS.Text;
        USR.USR_COMPANY = txtCOMPANY.Text;
        //USR.USR_COMPANY = "=chrome..69i57.13150j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8";
        DB.TBL_USERS.Add(USR);
        DB.SaveChanges();


        dataGridView1.DataSource = "";
        dataGridView1.DataSource = DB.TBL_USERS.ToList();
    }

    private void btnDELETE_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var qdel = DB.TBL_USERS.Where(x => x.ID == IDGRID).ToList();

        foreach (var item in qdel)
        {
            DB.TBL_USERS.Remove(item);

        }
        DB.SaveChanges();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = "";
        dataGridView1.DataSource = DB.TBL_USERS.ToList();
    }

    private void dataGridView1_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        IDGRID = (int)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ID"].Value;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Was there a length restriction on the field in a previous version? Perhaps you didn't update your model. What is the maximum length properties value for the field in your model designer?

Comment: If that were the case, thousands of developers would have noticed 15 years ago. Post an *actual, reproducible example*. Including the table shcema. I suspect that just by creating the example you'll find the bug, eg. writing to the wrong column, or using an entity with a maximum of 70 characters

Comment: BTW is `USR_COMPANY` really treated as a blob? That's what `nvarchar(max)` means. It *doesn't* mean "store any string". It's meant to store 2GB-long strings, not 200-500 character long notes or descriptions

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i used nvarchar(max) as a test to see if the limit comes from SQL or not .. how can i change the 70 character limit from entity ... consider that im a newbie to programming.

Comment: @RomanoZumbé how can i do that ?

Comment: I have a german version of visual studio, so I'm not exactly sure what the menupoints are named in your version, but it works something like this. Open your model designer, right click somewhere on the background (not any table object), select update model from database (or something like that), in the dialog select the update register, select tables and click on the finish button

Comment: @MohsenK Search for the string "70" in your project. 70 is an arbitrary number. The default size used by various tool (eg Table designer) is 50. That's why there are so many `nvarchar(50)` fields in many databases. Apart from that, it's not possible to guess what is going on with the model or table schema. You *don't* have to do *anything* special to save strings of any length.

Answer (score 0):

considering the comments i found out where the problem is :

initially the model was created with a SQL table that used `nvarchar(50)` and after changing that to `nvarchar(500)` or `nvarchar(max)` the `model.edmx` needed to be updated ... after updating the model all things worked like a charm .